# Replace xml attribute with a String containing slashes

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace an attribute within an xml using exclusively `sed` .

I already found on StackOverflow a method that works on an attribute consisting of letters. It doesn't work on attributes containing slashes `/` though.

The `XML` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Environment WorkingFolder="" Provider="">
    <tag> 
    </tag>
</Environment>
```

I'm trying to replace `WorkingFolder=""` with `WorkingFolder="/some/path/"`

So the `XML` would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Environment WorkingFolder="/some/path/" Provider="">
    <tag> 
    </tag>
</Environment>
```

I get an error if I try to just:

```
sed -E 's/WorkingFolder="[^"]*"/WorkingFolder="/some/path/"/' file.xml
```

Because of the slashes `/`.

So what I did is used another `sed` command to escape the slashes `/`:

```
path=$(echo /some/path/ | sed 's_/_\\/_g')

sed -E 's/WorkingFolder="[^"]*"/WorkingFolder="$path"/' file.xml
```

The problem now is that the `$path` variable doesn't expand because of the single quote `'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's|WorkingFolder="[^"]*"|WorkingFolder="/some/path/"|' file.xml
```